# how to hide the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm already stuck for almost a day but still unable to fix this issue. I already search in web and the common recommendation in using this code `$('#Modal').modal('hide')`. This is working in my other function that are using modal but there is an specific function that unable to close. Here is the sample where I able to close the modal.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnProcedureAccessSave', function (event) {
    HideAllInModal();
    $('#divLoadingInModal').show();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/AddProcedureAccess',
        data: {
            UserID: $('#txtNewUserID').val(),
            ProcedureID: $('#txtSelectedProcedureID').val(),
            __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken(),
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response['success'] == true) {
                $('#Modal').modal('hide');
                ProcedureAccessMarkUpUpdate(response['data']);
            }
            else {
                $('#divLoadingInModal').hide();
                $('#divProcedureAccessInModal').show();
                ValidationError(response['error']);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            $('#divLoadingInModal').hide();
            $('#divProcedureAccessInModal').show();
            JavaScriptError(jqXHR, exception);
        }
    });
});
```

here the code that I unable to close the modal

```
function DeleteUserProcedureAccess(ID) {
    HideAllInModal();
    $('#divLoadingInModal').show();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/DeleteUserProcedureAccess',
        data: {
            UserProcedureID: ID,
            __RequestVerificationToken: gettoken()
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#' + ID).remove();
            $('#Modal').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            $('#Modal').modal('hide');
            JavaScriptError(jqXHR, exception);
        }
    });
}
```

my HTML Code

```
<div class="modal fade show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="Modal" style="padding-right: 17px;" aria-modal="true">

    @*Loading Modal*@
    <div id="divLoadingInModal" class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document" style="display:none; width:110px;">
        <div class="modal-content" style="text-align:center">
            <img src="~/Content/Assets/img/5.gif"  style="width:100px; height:100px; margin:5px;"/>
            <h5>Loading...</h5>
        </div>
    </div>

    @*Procedure Access Modal*@
    <div id="divProcedureAccessInModal" class="modal-dialog modal-md modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><label id="lblProcedureAccessModalHeader"></label></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body needs-validation">
                <input id="txtProcedureAccessID" type="hidden" />
                <div class="form-Group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input id="txtNewUserID" type="hidden" />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="txtProcedureAccessname" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                    </div>
                    <label id="err_ProcedureAccessUserID"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer bg-whitesmoke">           
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-shadow" id="btnProcedureAccessSave">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you have added display none and class="modal fade show" can i know why?

Comment: just run this $('#Modal').modal('hide'); in console and check modal is hiding or not.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the right id of modal div 
for example if you using this $('#Modal').modal('hide'); that means your modal id is "Modal". you are using a correct way of hiding the model but your jquery selector is wrong id. use a correct jquery selector id for example if your modal when you are showing it you are calling -     $('#divLoadingInModal').show(); same wat  to hide you need to call 
    $('#divLoadingInModal').hide(); or     $('#divLoadingInModal').modal('hide');
**** Make sure you are using a correct jquery selector in $ function .

Comment: my modal ID is **Modal**. **divLoadingInModal** and **divProcedureAccessInModal** is inside the **Modal**. Basically I only show the divLoadingInModal when I call a function the server and close it after the request. I Attach my HTML Code for more clarification

Comment: why you add a modal inside a modal code its wrong. even if you need to call a modal inside a modal you just need to call it in the right way.  provide the JS fiddle or code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the fade class in your modal, which would disable the hide option. Get rid of that class, other reasons would be the duplicate id of the modal, you can try testing out if the id is recognized. Another reason would be the bootstrap version
New Way

Old Way